# SocketTimeOut exception while using Retrofit

Tags: android

I am just trying to do post api call using Retrofit.The server is responding with correct data.I checked with Postman(Chrome). My code is as follows

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements retrofit2.Callback>{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();


    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://kokanplaces.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0

    ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<CityModel>> call = apiService.getCitiesList();;
    //asynchronous call
    call.enqueue(this);
}


@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<CityModel>> call, Response<List<CityModel>> response) {
    int code = response.code();
    if (code == 200) {
         for (CityModel cityModel : response.body()) {
               System.out.println(
                        cityModel.getCityname() + " (" + cityModel.getCityId() + ")");
            }           


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Did not work: " + String.valueOf(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<List<CityModel>> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
    t.printStackTrace();

}
```

}

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@POST("wp-json/getCities")
Call<List<CityModel>> getCitiesList();
```

}

Every time it is throwing *Socket timeout* exception.

Any solution will be great help.

Answer (score 1):

I met the problems like you before. I fixed by adding custom `OkHttpClient`:

```
Constants.TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 60;
private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT_CONNECTION, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT_CONNECTION, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//                .sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())
                .build();
        return okHttpClient;
    }
```

and retrofitAdapter:

```
retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(ConstantApi.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .client(getOkHttpClient())
                        .build();
```

Remember `readTimeout` is 0, I am using retrofit 2.1.0. Default timeout of retrofit is 10 seconds. I tried to set `readTimeout` is 60 seconds but no effect.

Comment: I found my mistake that

Comment: instead of                                                                                           ApiInterface apiService =          ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);     I need to call      retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class); Other things were fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Topic tags:** Socket closed, socket timeout

**Explanation:** Retrofit maintains connection which is locking socket.

**More:** https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146

**SOLUTION:**
configure **connectionPool** like in below example:

```
private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0,1,TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
            .build();
    return okHttpClient;
}
```

Please remember to mark answer as correct :)